# Adafruit Feather 32u4 BLE compatible with Software SPI?

Tags: bluetooth, spi, adafruit, software

Let me preface by saying that I am not super experienced with electronics. I have an Adafruit Feather 32u4 that is using Hardware SPI to communicate over Bluetooth. Unfortunately, I'm also hoping to use the SD library, which also uses Hardware SPI. I am hoping to change the board to use Software SPI instead, so that the two may work together.

The Bluefruit code by default has the following commented out:

```
/* ...software SPI, using SCK/MOSI/MISO user-defined SPI pins and then user selected CS/IRQ/RST */
Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI ble(BLUEFRUIT_SPI_SCK, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_MISO,
                             BLUEFRUIT_SPI_MOSI, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS,
                             BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST);
```

Which leads me to believe I could use SW SPI but simply uncommenting this and commenting out the HW SPI doesn't seem to work.

I am just not sure if it's not compatible with the board, or I need to do more than this...?

Comment: SPI is a bus. you can wire more devices only use different  CS pin. some SD modules make problems on bus. the Adafruit SD module is OK

Comment: my comment applies to hardware SPI. two different sw SPI or sw SPI with hw SPI can't work together on the same pins

Answer (score 2):

Read SparkFun's guide, [Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI)](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-peripheral-interface-spi/all), especially the [multiple slaves](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-peripheral-interface-spi/all#slave-select-ss) section:

---

> #### Multiple slaves
>
> There are two ways of connecting multiple slaves to an SPI bus:
>
> 1. In general, each slave will need a separate SS line. To talk to a particular slave, you'll make that slave's SS line low and keep the
>    rest of them high (you don't want two slaves activated at the same
>    time, or they may both try to talk on the same MISO line resulting in
>    garbled data). Lots of slaves will require lots of SS lines; if you're
>    running low on outputs, there are binary decoder chips that can
>    multiply your SS outputs.
>
> [image]
>
> 2. On the other hand, some parts prefer to be daisy-chained together, with the MISO (output) of one going to the MOSI (input) of the next.
>    In this case, a single SS line goes to all the slaves. Once all the
>    data is sent, the SS line is raised, which causes all the chips to be
>    activated simultaneously. This is often used for daisy-chained shift
>    registers and addressable LED drivers.
>
> [image]
>
> Note that, for this layout, data overflows from one slave to the next,
> so to send data to any one slave, you'll need to transmit enough data
> to reach all of them. Also, keep in mind that the first piece of data
> you transmit will end up in the last slave.
>
> This type of layout is typically used in output-only situations, such
> as driving LEDs where you don't need to receive any data back. In
> these cases you can leave the master's MISO line disconnected.
> However, if data does need to be returned to the master, you can do
> this by closing the daisy-chain loop (blue wire in the above diagram).
> Note that if you do this, the return data from slave 1 will need to
> pass through all the slaves before getting back to the master, so be
> sure to send enough receive commands to get the data you need.